# Equivilant of PHPs session_regenerate_id in classic asp

Tags: php, asp-classic, sessionid

Hopefully a nice easy question to which I hope someone knows the answer.

I would like to know if there is an [equivalent method](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php) to that of the `session_regenerate_id()` which you might find in `PHP` but for `class ASP`.

For those of you who do not know PHP but know classic ASP the result of this function is the [regeneration of a new Session ID keeping the session data](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php).

Comment: So you want the ASP equivalent of PHPs `session_regenerate_id()`? Your question is not very clear.

Comment: I cannot see such a function and would guess you need to copy the contents, kill the session, create a new session and then copy the contents back in. I haven't touched ASP in a long time though so could well be very wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no equivalent method in ASP Classic.

The only option is to use `Session.Abandon`. This destroys the session **after** the scripts are executed and the page loaded.

A new session will be created on the next call, with a new ID.